# How set [self varNavigationController] for not being null in my ViewController?

Tags: iphone, navigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

noob writing,

I'm trying to use a Navigation Controller, but the method pushViewController doesn't work as it is 'null'.

At the same time I've tried the same code in a Navigation Based App Template, and I can do it work.

My question is, how can I make that [self myVariableforNavigationController] not to be null in my ViewBased App?? I've tried everything inside the AppDelegate but without success.

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can add your own navigation controller. And assign as it with the main controller to root viewcontroller.

Now when you want to push to another view you can easily do it as your view based application have the navigationcontroller as the rootViewCOntroller. So, you can't have the value to null from now onwards and you can push to second view easily.

Let me know if still having doubt.

Comment: Ok, now [self varNavigationController] is not null anymore, but the method pushViewController doesn't work. :(

Comment: UINavigationController *navigation1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

Comment: Try this:     UINavigationController *navigation1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
And Now you can push the view from [navigation1 pushviewcontroller: secondView animated:YES]l